# ASP.NET Web-API Help-API Generator?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am wondering if anyone can point me to which *Web-Api Help Generator* I should use.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695095/asp-net-web-api-automatically-generate-api-documentation) but it is already a year old and seems to be outdated.

I think ApiExplorer is now [Web API Help](http://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.webapi.helppage).

The post also talks about [Swagger](https://github.com/miketrionfo/Swagger.Net) which from some demos looks a lot nicer and seems like you can do like post requests and such but I am unsure if it still in development as it's been like a year since the last update.

Anyone have any experience with either of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Web API Help Page" package (Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage) is built on top of ApiExplorer.

- Web API Help Page generates documentation pages and adds them to your project.
- ApiExplorer gives you a lower-level API that just gives you the API descriptions, which you can use to create documentation.

See: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/creating-api-help-pages

I haven't used Swagger. From the readme, it's also built on top of ApiExplorer.